# Maximum distance an arm can be extended with a trigonometrical question

Tags: trigonometry

This is a past paper multiple choice question that I am attempting and all of the answer sheets says that its $13$ while my answer is $17$. The question is as follows:

"The distance, d meters, of an arm of a shaping machine from its starting position can be modelled by the equation $d=12\cos\theta+5\sin\theta$. The MAXIMUM distance, in metres, from the starting point is: $5, 12, 13,17$."

Isn't the maximum values $\sin\theta$ and  $\cos\theta$ can go up to both $1$ so shouldn't $12*1+5*1=17 $ ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: For some fixed angle $\theta$, $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ cannot be equal to $1$ at the same time.

Comment: Waw yes that's true! So then the answer is actually $5$ ?

Comment: Can't be $5$, set $\theta = 0$ and you get $\cos(0) = 1$, $\sin(0) = 0$, so have $d=12$. But a larger value can still be produced.

Answer (score 1):

We have the distance $d$ of the arm as a function of the angle $\theta$, that is:

$$d(\theta) = 12\cos \theta + 5\sin \theta$$

A standard optimization problem. We search for $d'(\theta) = 0$ to find extreme points:

$$d'(\theta) = -12\sin \theta + 5\cos \theta$$

We search for the zeroes, that is:

$$0 = -12\sin \theta + 5\cos \theta$$

$$12\sin \theta = 5\cos \theta$$
$$12\frac{\sin \theta}{\cos \theta} = 5$$
$$12\tan \theta = 5$$
$$\tan \theta = \frac{5}{12}$$
We solve this by using the $\arctan$ function in our calculator and get 
$$\theta = \arctan\left(\frac{5}{12}\right) = 0.39479..$$
We plug this value of $\theta$ into $d(\theta)$ and get

$$d(\arctan(5/12)) =13$$
Thus, the answer is $13$, which is in the given choices.

Answer (score 0):

Or, more quickly:
$d=12cos(\theta)+5sin(\theta)=Acos(\alpha)cos(\theta)+Asin(\alpha)sin(\theta)$
$$A=\sqrt{(12^2+5^2)}=13 $$ $$  \alpha=\arctan{(5/12)}$$
$$d=13cos(\theta-\alpha)$$